# How to write a VB script to find multiple keywords within all cells and highlight each keyword?

Tags: vba, excel, keyword-search

I'm currently having a list of keywords (e.g. CFO, CTO, interim manager, etc.) and I want to have a macro assigned to a button that can search all cells in Column E of Sheet 1 which contain these keywords then give back the result as well as highlight the keyword in the cell.

- Each keyword is in a separate cell in Column A of Sheet 2.
- If there is one keyword in the list, it will search for one but if there are more, it will search for combination.

Here is the screenshot to illustrate what I've describe above

[image]

I have found something over the Internet with suggestion to use AutoFilter but I can only use it to perform a search for one keyword. This is what I've tried:

```
Sub EmailFilter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "=*" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A10") & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try any code?

Comment: @bzimor As I've said in my post, I've tried AutoFilter but I can only get back result for the first keyword in the list.

Comment: @bzimor Here is the code that I've tried. Excuse me if it's lame as I just started learning VBA few days ago. 

    Sub EmailFilter()
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A12") & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
        End With
          Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

Comment: I mean if you tried and encounter any error, you should post your question with code then ask to solve problem. Thats why I asked.

Comment: @bizmor Sorry, this is my first time here asking for help so I might not get it right at the first step. I've updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will color all the matches with the same color(I have chosen blue). You can write this macro in a module and then create a Form Control Button and assign the macro to the button.

```
Sub macro()
Dim a As Integer, x As String, mystring As String
a = 2
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells(a, 1).Activate
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    x = ActiveCell.Value
    p = Len(x)
    Application.GoTo Sheet1.Range("E2")
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        mystring = ActiveCell.Value
        If InStr(mystring, x) > 0 Then
            Position = InStr(1, mystring, x)
            If Position > 0 Then
                ActiveCell.Characters(Position, p).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
    a = a + 1
    Application.GoTo Sheet2.Cells(a, 1)
Loop
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any other specific requirements so that the code can be altered. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I've tried your code but unfortunately it does not color the match.

Comment: The limitations of the code is that-  1. You should not have any spaces in either of the colums, i.e in Column 1 of Sheet2 or Column E of Sheet1. 2. the text should exactly match, i.e. the text should be in the same case whether it is upper or lower. 3. The seach starts from the first row itself in the respective columns that you have asked to search.  And I have tried again and found that it is working fine. If you can edit your question, providing any screenshots of the two sheets, it could be  much helpful. You can even share a sample of the Columns which can help in resolving the issue.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what content and keywords look like.

Comment: I have edited the code and guess it will work fine now. kindly check and let me know. Moreover, the names of the sheets should be changed if you are using any other names in your workbook.

Comment: Your code actually colors the whole cell but as I stated in my question, I only need to highlight the keyword in the cell.

Comment: I have updated the code as per your requirements. Hope it helps! Please check it and let me know if it is working fine and/or you need anything else.